# How do I deal with the error I get when trying to change the latitude and longitude data type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, alter

I'm trying to change data types of a table, but I have a problem with latitude & longitude columns.

Latitude and longitude values have comma and data types are string : 38,1736150327 (string)

I want to change the columns as : 38.1736150327 (float)

But when I run this:

```
ALTER TABLE col_name ALTER COLUMN "LATITUDE" TYPE float USING REGEXP_REPLACE("LATITUDE",',','.')::float;
```

I got this error:

```
SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "3.890,225,016"
```

Everything looks fine when I use select (same table). There is no error and values are proper as expected.

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE("LATITUDE",',','.')::float, REGEXP_REPLACE("LONGITUDE",',','.')::float 
from col_name;
```

```
40.207785282        38.1736150327
40.2173539200216    38.247297941994
```

I couldn't figure out what the problem was when using "alter".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select REGEXP_REPLACE('3.890,225,016',',','.'); 3.890.225,016` From docs [String Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html): *regexp_replace Replaces the substring that is the first match to the POSIX regular expression pattern, or all such matches if the g flag is used*. I think you need the `g` flag.

Comment: I should have added, when you did the SELECT was that against all the values in col_name? Because it looks like at least one is not following the pattern shown here 38,1736150327.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you for your quick response. Sorry if I caused any misunderstanding, .  I did select all values in LATITUDE, LONGITUDE columns in col_name table but the output that I share only examples to show results here.  (by the way "col_name" was a terrible alias for a table, I missed it while typing, I didn't want to write original name of table)

Comment: The error `invalid input syntax for type double precision: "3.890,225,016` is pretty specific and correct as that is not correct input for `float`.  To get to that point using `REGEXP_REPLACE()` as you have I see the input being: `select REGEXP_REPLACE('3,890,225,016',',','.'); 3.890,225,016`.  At this point all I can think of is that the select is being done on different `col_name` table then the `ALTER`, maybe a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue?

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned above, there are numbers with multiple commas in the data set. I spotted some. When I used select & regexp, I found the same error occurred but after scrolling down in the dataset. I guess it's because of the database application I'm using. Thank you for your help @AdrianKlaver